# Why am I getting the error: "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined" on flask/python/html project?

Tags: python, html, validation, flask

I'm creating a flask/python/html project that asks the user for their name. I'm trying to use wtforms to validate the input.

This is the html (mainScraper.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block head %}
<link rel ="stylesheet" href = "mainScraper.css">
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<h1> This is the main page </h1>

  <p> Please enter your name: </p>
  <br/>
  <form action = "mainScraper", method = "POST">

    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.username.label }}
    {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.submit }}

 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the flask/python:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import SubmitField, StringField
    from wtforms.validators import data_required, length



    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = "34Secret56"

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('mainScraper.html')

    name = ' '

    class NameForm(FlaskForm):
        username = StringField('Name', validators = [data_required(),length(min = 1)])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')


    @app.route('/mainScraper', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def mainScraper():
        
        form = NameForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            global name
            name = form.username.data

            return render_template('general.html')
            
        return render_template('mainScraper.html', form=form)
```

I want to make sure at least one character is submitted before moving on to the next html page (from the mainScraper.html to the general.html).

But I'm getting this error from my mainScraper.html file: "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined" and I'm confused as to why, because I defined 'form' in the corresponding method of the python file, mainScraper. And I’m not sure how else I should validate my forms in html because most online videos or websites I’ve seen use flask-WTF or WTForms with {{ form.csrf_token}} in a html file

Also I’m not using an IDE for the python file, but React for the html file, is that a problem?
If so, what IDE do you suggest I use for the python and html file?

Comment: Could you clarify, why you are using two routes that do exactly the same, except for creating the Form? Because I think you might be using the default route "/", if that is the case, then consider either merging "mainScraper()" and "index()", OR create to form also in "index()"

Comment: Ok, you were correct. Having "mainScraper()" and "index()" was causing me the error. I merged them together as index() with the default route "/" and now I'm not getting that error. Thanks!